# Subtracting No. of Hours from date format

Tags: excel

i need to subtract the following in Excel:

DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss from a specific number of hours.

for example: 2/27/17 15:34 - 6.02.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel datetime values are floating point double values where

1 day = 1.0

1 hour = 1/24  = 0.0416666666666667

1 minute = 1/24/60 = 0.000694444444444444

So if your `6.02` means `6.02` hours = 6 hours and 2/100 hours = 6 hours 1 minute and 12 seconds and if your date `2/27/17 15:34` is in cell `A1`, then

`=A1-(6.02/24)`

will result in `2/27/17 09:32:48`.

Answer (score 0):

No need for extra calculation because they are all data/time data internally. When A1 is `2017-02-17 15:34`, type `2017-02-17 6:02` in B1, and then type `=a1-b1` in C1.